# Ownership Belongs To

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about a phrase in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folsom_Library):

> For a short period of time, ***the ownership of the library belonged to*** Amos Eaton, a local scientist and educator, when he obtained rights to the Old Bank Place after the Rensselaer School changed its name to the Rensselaer Institute and moved to Van Der Heyden Mansion, a nearby location.

Is it standard English to say that "*the ownership of something belongs to somebody*"?

Comment: What incorrect sentence?  [I don't see any incorrect sentence...](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Folsom_Library&type=revision&diff=706429143&oldid=704231594)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's a very odd phrasing. It sounds to me like it's saying that the ownership belonged to Mr Eaton, rather than that the library belonged to Mr Eaton. He didn't own the liberary, but he owned the ownership of the library. At best it's clumsy. I'd say it's flat wrong.

Typically we'd say simply, "The library belonged to Amos Eaton" or "The library was owned by Amos Eaton".

When something changes hands, we sometimes say, "Ownership passed to ..."

I suppose you could say, "Ownership of the library was asserted by Amos Eaton" or "Ownership was held by Amos Eaton", but those are awkward and unnecessarilyi wordy.